# Totaly delete file from Raspbian system

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian, delete-file

I want to delete Files from my Raspberry Pi without moving it to the Trash can using Python. I tried `os.remove(file)`, but it's moved into the Trash. Can I delete the file without moving it into the Trash or can I empty the Trash?

Comment: Deleting a file like that will not move it to the trash.

Comment: It will, I tested it.

Comment: You can always try shell command `rm -rf file` with subprocess

Comment: `rm file` (wihtout -rf) works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.system('rm ' + path)` is working.